# Cosmos DB Query Adds RUs when using OR

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a simple core sql query that gets a count of rows. If i do the EXISTS and the IN separately, it's around 2/3RUs, but if i do a (EXISTS "OR" IN) -- I can even do (EXISTS "OR" TRUE), then it jumps up to 45RU. It makes more since for me to do 2 different queries than 1. Why does the OR cause the RU consuption to go up?

These are my queries that I've tried and I've experimented on.

```
 SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM ROOT r.  -- 850 rows, 2-3RUs

 SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM ROOT r WHERE IS_NULL(r.deletedAt) -- 830 rows, 2-3RUs

 SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM ROOT r WHERE IS_NULL(r.deletedAt) AND r.id IN (......). 830 rows, 2-3RUs

 SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM ROOT r WHERE IS_NULL(r.deletedAt) AND EXISTS(SELECT s FROM s IN r.shared WHERE s.id = ID) -- 840rows, 2-3RUs

 SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM ROOT r WHERE IS_NULL(r.deletedAt) AND (EXISTS(SELECT s FROM s IN r.shared WHERE s.id = ID) OR r.id IN (...)) -- 840rows,  45RUs
```

This is also cross-listed on [Microsoft Q/A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/872376/ru-consumption-doesn39t-seem-correct.html) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no internal view on CosmosdB engine and below is just a general guess.

While there may be tricks involved regarding data cardinality, how your index is set up and if/how the predicate tree could be pruned, but overall it is not too surprising that `OR` is a harder query. **You can't have a covering index for `OR`-predicate and that requires data lookups.**

For index-covered `AND`s only, basically:

1. get matching entries from indexes for indexable predicates and take intersection.
2. return count

With `OR`-s you can't work on indexes alone:

1. get matching entries from indexes for indexable predicates and take intersection.
2. look up documents (or required parts)
3. Evaluate non-indexable predicates (like `A OR B`) on all matching documents
4. return count

Obviously the second requires a lot more computation and memory. Hence, higher RU. Query engine can do all kind of tricks, but the fact is that they must get extra data to make sure your "hard" predicates are taken into account.

BTW, if unhappy with RU, then you should always check which/how indexes were applied and if you can improve anything by setting up different indexes.
See: [Indexing metrics in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/index-metrics).

Having more complex queries have higher RU is still to be expected, though.